# Find the biggest number formed by digits of input numer

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that return the biggest number formed by the digits from an input integer number. 
So if the input = 123584
output should be = 854321

My code is -

```
def maxNumber(inputNumber):
    x = len(str(inputNumber))
    max_number = []
    result= []
    while(x>0):
        max_number.append(inputNumber%10)
        inputNumber = inputNumber/10
        x -= 1
    while(x<(len(str(max_number)))):
        result.append(max(max_number))
        x += 1
    return result

print maxNumber(1238675)
```

and off-course the output is not as I want. Please help. I am eager to learn all possible way to do it.

Comment: It is not homework, but that's Ok, I learned few new things

Comment: Erm ... only one answer handles negative numbers ;-)

Comment: It could be an interesting challenge to implement this using pure arithmetic, without string functions. Anyone?

Comment: @thg435 Good point!! How could I have missed that challenge. Please see below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more reliable than most answers given so far ;-)

```
def max_number(n):
    s = str(n)
    digits = sorted(s, reverse=n>0)
    return int(''.join(digits))

print max_number(231)    
print max_number(-231)    
print max_number(+231)
```

And good point - I missed the option of doing it with number alone - here it is for completeness. :)

```
from math import *

def max_number(n):
    digit_count = int(log(abs(n+1),10)) + 1 
    digits = sorted([(n / 10 ** (x - 1) % 10)  for x in range(digit_count,0,-1) ], reverse=True)
    return reduce(lambda x, y:10*x + y, digits)

print max_number(1000)
print max_number(999)
print max_number(2345128)
print max_number(231)
```

Comment: There are two big problems with that: first, floating-point numbers fundamentally *are not* decimal numbers; and second, you'll always want to put the decimal point at the end after all the digits, so it's not even an interesting problem.

Comment: The big number should only be formed by the digits, as written in the question. The sign should not be included.

Answer (score 8):

```
def maxNumber(inputNumber):
    return int(''.join(sorted(str(inputNumber), reverse=True)))
```

Answer (score 7):

The biggest number is formed by sorting the digits in descending order.  This can be achived using the `rverse=True` parameter to `sorted()`:

```
def max_digit_permutation(n):
    return int("".join(sorted(str(n), reverse=True)))
```

Comment: This is why I am learning Python as my first language..it teaches you a lot and very concise way

Answer (score 2):

**sort** the string of number,  `reverse` it, `join` it and convert to `int`

```
>>> x=123584
>>> int(''.join(sorted(str(x))[::-1]))
854321
```

Comment: `[::-1]` can be nasty on memory if the number is _huge_

Comment: Oh, wow, it's is easy, and I am not getting it..time to put more efforts :)

Comment: @Varun to be honest this kinda one line stuff comes from knowing the language very well, its often better to learn the long way first.

Answer (score 1):

You could just treat the number as a list of single digits and then sort the list in decreasing order.

What about something like this:

```
num = str(123584)
int(''.join(sorted(num, reverse=True)))
```